# Move highcharts yAxis.tickPositioner callback function outside to some util function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts, callback, closures

I'm trying to implement highcharts with multiple y-axis and need to set yAxis.tickPositioner callback function for each of the y-axis. So instead of writing the duplicate code in each callback I need to create a util function to which I can pass values like dataMin and dataMax which is only accessible in the tickPositioner callback function.

```
chartOptions {
    xAxis: {
        tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8]
    },

    yAxis: {
        tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

            if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
                for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                    positions.push(tick);
                }
            }
            return positions;
        }
    },
}
```

instead I want something like this which has all the values like this.dataMin and this.dataMax available in the util function

```
    chartOptions {
        xAxis: {
            tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8]
        },

        yAxis: {
            tickPositioner: this.utilFunction();
        },
    }

utilFunction() {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

            if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
                for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                    positions.push(tick);
                }
            }
            return positions;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have access to an axis by `this` in `utilFunction`, if you assign it in this way:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositioner: this.utilFunction
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4958/

---

If you need to use some other context in the function, you can pass the reqired values through arguments:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositioner: function() {
    utilFunction(this.dataMin, this.dataMax);
  }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4959/